# How to filter sub-items, QTreeView using QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I want to be able to filter every item under the 'Parameter' column. I am using a QSortFilterProxyModel and a QLineEdit to try and filter out specific levels from the QTreeView, however I unable to filter out any level/sublevel besides the 'Rootlevel'.

How can I fix this implementation to be able to filter any of the levels and not just the 'RootLevel'?

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore,QtWidgets
import sys

class MainFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        tree = {'RootLevel':{
                    "Level1": {"Level1_item1":14, "Level1_item2":12, "Level1_item3":3.55},
                    "Level2": {
                        "Level2_SubLevel1": {"Level2_SubLevel1_item1":3.52, "Level2_SubLevel1_item2":2.55, "Level2_SubLevel1_item3":13},
                        "Level2_SubLevel2": {"Level2_SubLevel2_item1":2, "Level2_SubLevel2_item2":4, "Level2_SubLevel2_item3":3.11}
                        },
                    "Level3": {"Level3_item1":12, "Level3_item2":13.55, "Level3_item3":122}}
        }

        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        self.filterEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.filterEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)

        self.root_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.root_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Level','Values'])

        self.fill_model_from_json(self.root_model.invisibleRootItem(), tree)

        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.root_model)

        self.tree.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.tree.header().setMinimumSectionSize(300)
        self.filterEdit.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegExp(text)

    def fill_model_from_json(self, parent, d):
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for key, value in d.items():
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(key))
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    parent.appendRow(it)
                    self.fill_model_from_json(it, value)
                else:
                    it2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                    parent.appendRow([it, it2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter the second column then you must set it using the [`filterKeyColumn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterKeyColumn-prop) property, if you want to filter at lower levels then you must enable the [`recursiveFilteringEnabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#recursiveFilteringEnabled-prop) property, and it is recommended that you expand all the items using [`expandAll()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#expandAll) so that the filtering is visible.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        tree = {
            "RootLevel": {
                "Level1": {
                    "Level1_item1": 14,
                    "Level1_item2": 12,
                    "Level1_item3": 3.55,
                },
                "Level2": {
                    "Level2_SubLevel1": {
                        "Level2_SubLevel1_item1": 3.52,
                        "Level2_SubLevel1_item2": 2.55,
                        "Level2_SubLevel1_item3": 13,
                    },
                    "Level2_SubLevel2": {
                        "Level2_SubLevel2_item1": 2,
                        "Level2_SubLevel2_item2": 4,
                        "Level2_SubLevel2_item3": 3.11,
                    },
                },
                "Level3": {
                    "Level3_item1": 12,
                    "Level3_item2": 13.55,
                    "Level3_item3": 122,
                },
            }
        }

        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.filterEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(textChanged=self.onTextChanged)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.filterEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)

        self.root_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.root_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Level", "Values"])

        self.fill_model_from_json(self.root_model.invisibleRootItem(), tree)

        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(
            self, filterKeyColumn=1, recursiveFilteringEnabled=True
        )
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.root_model)

        self.tree.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.tree.header().setMinimumSectionSize(300)

        self.tree.expandAll()
        self.resize(640, 480)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegExp(text)

    def fill_model_from_json(self, parent, d):
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for key, value in d.items():
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(key))
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    parent.appendRow(it)
                    self.fill_model_from_json(it, value)
                else:
                    it2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                    parent.appendRow([it, it2])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]